# Проблема с отправкой формы Wordpress Contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Contactform 7 при отправке выдает ошибку "Одно или несколько полей содержат ошибку."
Но только если поле обязательное. Если поле сделать не обязательным, все отправляется нормально.

Сайт: https://izolir.ru

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: И в чём проблема-то? (исправь вопрос и приведи код формы)

Comment: Есть формы в Contact form7, если сделать поле обязательным оно выдает ошибку "Одно или несколько полей содержат ошибку.". Хотя в поле все заполнено правильно.

Comment: <code><label> Ваше имя
    [text* text-381] </label>

<label> Ваш e-mail
    [tel* tel-270] </label>


<label> Ваше сообщение (не обязательно)
    [textarea your-message] </label>

[submit "Отправить"]</code>

Comment: https://prnt.sc/24zpdqf

Comment: Зачем в кометах повторять то, что написано в вопросе (так и  не ответив на вопрос) и что тебе не понятно во фразе "исправь вопрос"?